# How to attach a dynamic file in a email template?

Tags: email-template, emailfileattachment

I'm trying to attach a file to an email templates.

This email template will be used in a workflow, so what I need is to send it everytime a condition is met in a opportunity. The file I need to attach is one of the file that is related with the opportunity, so it will be different in every email.

I just achieved to send always the same document (static). I also tried VF templates, but still is not working.

This is the code used in the VF template:

Congratulations! This is your new Visualforce Email Template

Have anyone do it before?

Thank you so much for your time.

Jorge

Comment: How exactly VF templates are not working?

Comment: Is not sending the email, maybe the problem is the recipientType that can't be oppotunity. 
This is my code:
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="prueba aval" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Opportunity" >
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Congratulations!
This is your new Visualforce Email Template.
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
<messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF">
      <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Attachments}" var="a"/>
</messaging:attachment>

</messaging:emailTemplate>

I'm new working with email templates, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Please edit your original post to include the details and code.  It is very difficult to view code in a comment.

Comment: Your apex:repeat should be around the messaging:attachment, not the opposite. However you can't do that because you can't put a apex:repeat as a direct child of messaging:template. Not sure if you can do this without writing apex code...